# Analyze Network events with xperf

Tags: c++, xperf

I have written a small tcp-client/server-thing for testing the xperf-`networkttrace` capabilities.
But as it seems I did do something wrong with xperf.
When I use the Xperf kernel group `NETWORK` or `DIAG+NETWORKTRACE` it just shows me the "casual" stuff and nothin about tcp/udp-reads and writes...

Anyone got an clue of how to get these information from xperf?
(did not find anything really helpful via google)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out, that the send and receive-actions are logged under the "Generic Events" section, as marks.

You can also find them "easily" if You post-process the etl-log into a human readable file and search for TCPRead/Write UDPRead/Write TCPDisconnect/Connect/Accept etc...